# UIViewController incorectly shows on its side

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have two views, when that app loads if the prefs match the users log in I am trying to load the next ViewController immediatly.

Each view normally shows in landscape and I have set the apps settings to only allow landscape. However when I try to load the second view immediatly from the first view "viewdidload" The second view appears on its side.

This is what my code looks like, this code is in a method that gets called from the first viewcontrollers viewdidload

```
currentProjectListViewController = [[CurrentProjectListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CurrentProjectListViewController" bundle:nil];


    [currentProjectListViewController setDelegate:self]; // set the delegate so it can access the returning method to update the view

    UIWindow* keyWindow= [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [keyWindow addSubview: currentProjectListViewController.view];

    [self presentViewController:currentProjectListViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I have no idea where to even start with this. it makes it to the second views viewdidload how ever like I say the view appears to be correct but its just on its side effectivly 90degrees incorrect.

any help making sure this apperar in landscape would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you adding view of currentProjectListViewController to UIWindow object and immediately after adding it as subview you are presenting it using presentViewController from the cureent ViewController.?

Answer (score 0):

I think your View hierarchy is somewhat wrong.

Why are you adding `view` of `currentProjectListViewController` to `UIWindow` object and immediately after adding it as `subview` you are presenting it using `presentViewController` from the current ViewController?

When you load and show the second ViewController, your `presentViewController` code should work.
You dont need to play with your `UIWIndow` object. Just make sure you dismiss your present view controller so as to reduce memory footprint and memory leaks.

Comment: okay. ill have ago at that. I am not really sure what im doing as im used to working with navigation controller however for ths project I need to be able to jump through views independantly depending on several vars through out the views.. it just seemed more logical to go this way. But im having issues trying to get it right.

Comment: okay I just tried what ou said and the view will not diaplay by just using presentViewController